# Ubuntu is not working on Windows 8 (64-bit) System

Tags: boot

Windows 8 (64-bit) System.I downloaded Ubuntu  and every thing going well and started installing it. Ubuntu is successfully installed and rebooted but then I get an error during Ubuntu's boot.The error  is:

```
Starting Windows didn't succeed. The reason may be changing software.
To solve this problem:
1. Insert installation disc of Windows and reboot pc
2. Choose language settings and click Next
3. Use Repair
If you dont own this disk contact with the administrtor.
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
State: 0xc000007b
```

Here i read for many users have the same problem that i have,I think Ubuntu is not working on Windows 8 (64-bit) System

Comment: You tried to use Wubi didn't you?  Wubi ***does not work with Windows 8*** and never has.  Probably never will.  Therefore, support for Wubi and Windows 8 isn't available.

Comment: Here http://goo.gl/wMzk3V Ubuntu sit said "If you have a PC with the Windows 8 logo or UEFI firmware, choose the 64-bit download. "
But this was wrong,because 

Ubuntu 13.04  64-bit & Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit both of them are not working on Windows 8.

Comment: Because Wubi ***does not work with Windows 8.***  Wubi support was dropped during the 13.04 dev cycle.  Did you try and use wubi?  The error you're getting suggests that.  You'll need to use Windows Boot Repair, either from a Windows Disk or a repair partition, or using media from the manufacturer, repair the Windows bootloader, then remove Wubi and install alongside Windows 8 using [answers here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), or use VirtualBox within the Windows environment.

Comment: Mostly correct. But the issue with wubi is not Windows 8 but gpt partitioning that all pre-installed Windows 8 systems have with UEFI secure boot. If you manually install Windows 8 in BIOS mode then you can use wubi. Ubuntu 12.04.2 and later all have secure boot, so they will work with Windows 8 and secure boot systems. But newer versions may have updates to work better with some of the very new hardware.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Thomas and Lion, Wubi cannot be used on Windows 8. But there are alternatives if you just use Ubuntu casually and don't want to create a dual-boot with dedicated partitions on your internal drive  (a bit more complex but still pretty easy):

- Install Ubuntu on an external USB HDD (I always have one ready to use as a rescue system)
- Install Ubuntu on the same drive, side-by-side with Windows (see [this post's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for the steps to take.
- Use a virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/%E2%80%8E). You can find many tutorials explaining how to do this step by step.